# Dynamic Range Selection & New Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

An Excel Master Sheet lists Items by Cost Center in Col A and then Dept. in Col B.  I need to create a dynamic range that can identify Items in each row by a specific Dept; then, select those Rows for those Items identified; then, copy and paste those rows onto a New Sheet that's Named for the Respective Dept in Column B.

Assuming that the Dept will always be in Column B, this is the code I've come up with thus far.  This code finds a new Dept. in Col B and adds a new sheet with the same Name.  I need a Code that will select the rows with the same Dept Name; copy the selection, then paste that info onto the newly created Sheet. Does Anyone Have Any Suggestions as to the approach?

```
Sub Breakout1975()
Dim I As String
Dim First As Variant

Range("B1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

  If ActiveCell.Value <> Selection.Offset(-1, 0) Then
    MsgBox ("The Program has identified a new Dept. in Cell:" & " " &_
    ActiveCell.Address)
    MsgBox (Selection)'just using this as a check for myself
    Sheets.Add.Name = Selection
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select 'advance to variable later
  End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: It's too bad your department names start in B1. An `.AutoFilter` would do this nicely but requires a header row.

Comment: I could insert a header row first before anything else, right?  I see what you're getting at.  We could simply use .autofilter to make visible those rows of items that correspond to the specific depts.  I get that, now.  Huh.  But, we are working with Federal Gov Data that requires us to break items out by spreadsheet with no other data (unfilitered data) on the sheet because we are uploading this sheet into yet another database.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to insert a header row, this routine uses `.AutoFilter` to split out the data. In addition, it makes use of the unique key property of a `Scripting.Dictionary`. You will have to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to your project.

```
Sub Split_Depts()
    Dim b As Long, w As Long
    Dim dDEPTs As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dDEPTs.CompareMode = TextCompare
    For w = 2 To Sheets.Count
        dDEPTs.Add Key:=Sheets(w).Name, Item:=w ' no need to check if dDEPTs.Exists, ws names are unique
    Next w
    With Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion  'change to your own sheet codename
        For b = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If Not dDEPTs.Exists(Trim(.Cells(b, "B").Value)) Then
                Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Trim(.Cells(b, "B").Value)
                dDEPTs.Add Key:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name, Item:=Sheets.Count
                If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=dDEPTs.Keys(UBound(dDEPTs.Keys))
                .Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
                .AutoFilter
            End If
        Next b
    End With
CleanUp:
    dDEPTs.RemoveAll
    Set dDEPTs = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you wanted it any quicker you could add lines to turn off screen updating, disable events, calculation, etc.